# Granting FTP users access to multiple folders on CentOS

Tags: centos, ftp, filesystems

I'm have a web server running **CentOS Linux 7.2.1511**. I do most of the mundane management tasks through **Plesk 12.5.30 Update #29** but I also SSH in and get dirty with the command line when I need to. This server is running several websites. I have several different contractors, each that are working on their own set of websites. E.g.

- ContractorA works on WebSite1, WebSite2 and Website3.
- ContractorB works on Website1 and Website4.

All websites are exist in their own directories under `/var/www/vhosts`. E.g.

- `/var/www/vhosts/website1.com`
- `/var/www/vhosts/website2.com`

How do I grant each contractor access to their respective sites without granting them access to all websites? I dont want to share credentials between users (i.e. create one FTP account per website and pass those out). I also need this to be scalable. I will be adding more contractors and more websites and I will need to be able to grant any contractor access to any website.

As far as I am aware I can only set one home directory per user. I tried creating symbolic links in home directories but the FTP clients weren't showing or following the symbolic links. Because the scalability issue, I dont think I can solve this simply with file permissions (but maybe I am wrong). I saw some suggestions to mount each folder in the users home directory but that is getting a little beyond my capabilities to comfortably perform and I dont want to screw up my HDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about "bind mount" ?

```
# mount -o bind /var/www/vhosts/website1.com/ /home/ContractorA/website1.com/
# mount -o bind /var/www/vhosts/website2.com/ /home/ContractorA/website2.com/
# mount -o bind /var/www/vhosts/website3.com/ /home/ContractorA/website3.com/

# mount -o bind /var/www/vhosts/website1.com/ /home/ContractorB/website1.com/
# mount -o bind /var/www/vhosts/website4.com/ /home/ContractorB/website4.com/
```

Unmount is the same as usual.

```
# umount /home/ContractorA/website1.com/
    :
```

Comment: That worked beautifully.  I know I didnt ask this before, but for completeness, can you add how to unmount them too?

Answer (score 1):

Configure the approriate SELinux booleans

List the related booleans

```
# semanage boolean -l | egrep 'ftp|http' | sort
```

Turn on booleans that may be applicable temporarily i.e.

```
# setsebool httpd_can_connect_ftp on
```

To turn a boolean on permanently use -P flag i.e.

```
# setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on
```

Comment: I dont see anywhere in these commands that specifies anything about individual user accounts or website folders. How will I specify access per user per website?